# UI Automation Com wrapper not finding child controls

Tags: ui-automation

I have a context menu (PopupMenuControlTrusted control from infragistics)

Using inspect.exe I can find the menu and sub menu items with no trouble
Using UI Automation Verify (http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/) I can find the menu item with some difficulty
I need to hover over the control to find it, at this point the context menu is found with the correct window handle but no children.
I have to then tell the program to find the context menu again at which point all the child menu items are found.

When I do this by code I can never find the children, TreeWalker.RawWalker.GetFirstChild(menu) is always returning null
I am referencing the UIAComWrapper (same as used in the UI Automation Verify tool)

I have tried using the ControlWalker, sending a CacheRequest.Current on the element but I am unable to find any child elements

Has someone had this problem before or can give me any guidance as what else to do?

**Edit**
I have actually found out that AutomationElement.FromPoint can find the inner element and from there I can use the tree walker to find the parent, the parent turns out to be the menu that I had before, but i still cannot find child elements from the menu, can anyone explain this? I am confused here

Comment: Sounds like there's a bug in the control, in that it's not adding its actual children to its automation children.  (The automation children are typically set up as an array; adding the child elements has to be done separately.)